# What would happen if I connected just an electric dryer coil to a 120v circuit?

Tags: electrical

What would happen if I connected an electric dryer coil to a 120v circuit

Comment: It would get hot.  What else do you want to know?  Please try to add some detail to your question so we can address everything.

Comment: Is the question “What would happen if an electric dryer coil rated at 240v is connected to a 110v circuit?”?

Comment: If it's a 240V coil, hooked up to a 120V source, it'd get hot, but a lot less hot than if it were hooked to 240V.  I don't see any obvious drawbacks.

Answer (score 4):

Almost all dryer circuits are wired for 240V with #10 wire and 30A breakers.  Typically dryers are designed around the practical limitations of that circuit, in which they must draw less than 24A in sum total.  Dryers aim for 23A so manufacturing variation doesn't put them over max.  Given say, 3 amps for the 120V motor and controls, that leaves about 20 amps for the 240V heater coils, or about 4800 watts.

Now if you grind through Ohm's Law and Watt's Law a few times, you notice something interesting.  In a true resistor (like that heating coil), when you cut voltage by half, you also cut amperage by half.  So on 120V, that same heater coil draws 10 amps. OK, but plug that into Watt's Law, and 120V x 10A = 1200 watts.  In other words, **when we halve voltage, we quarter power**.

It would take some small amount of rewiring to cause the 120V parts of the dryer to receive full 120V, but for the heating coil to receive 120V also.  Once this was accomplished, you'd have a dryer that would run normally in all respects, except its heating coil would work at 1/4 power.

That means it would take *much* longer to dry clothes.  It might not be an overall cost savings, but it would work on a 120V circuit.  It would probably need to be a 20A circuit, because 10A heater + 3A motor = 13A. This would be so slow to dry that it would qualify as a *continuous load*, which means derating it by 125%, giving 16.25 amps, which is too much for a 15A circuit.  It would need to be a 20A circuit, and it would only leave 3.75A of additional useful load for other appliances.

Answer (score 3):

As I learned the hard way (as in, I answered a question thinking it was 1/2 and then got the explanation that it was 1/4), you will get ~ 25% of the heat that you would get at 240V.

The key expressions are:

> E = I R

which means Voltage = Current x Resistance

This can be rearranged to:

> I = E / R

which means Current = Resistance / Voltage

Now for some historical reason (I am sure I can find out, but I'm not bothering to do so - in enough of a rabbit hole already...), voltage is referred to as both E (as in Ohm's Law above) and as V (which makes a lot more sense in English - V for Voltage). Power is stated as:

> P = V x I

So the power - which is your heat - is V x I. and I = E / R. Which means P = V x (V / R). Or P = V squared / R.

Which means, in the end, that if you cut the voltage in 1/2 then you cut the **power == heat goes down to 1/4.**

For a specific example, if your dryer ran at 24 A x 240 V = 5,760 W, at 120 V it will be 12 A x 120 V = 1,440 W. The neat thing is we don't actually need to know the resistance since that is always the same. (Actually, resistance does change a little bit with temperature but not enough to make a big difference here).

**End result: Your clothes will take ~ 4 x as long to dry.**